# Trazer gestor e funcionário que estão na mesma tabela

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma tabela de **EMPREGADOS** e outra chamada **HIER_SAP**. Na **HIER_SAP** possuo dois campos importantes para o que eu quero, 
que são os campos **CODSUP** e **CODFUNC**. Para cada **CODFUNC**(funcionário) tenho um correspondente **CODSUP**(gestor). Bem, o que eu preciso
é pegar o gestor do funcionário na tabela **EMPREGADOS**. Aí fiz essa query:

```
SELECT
         --SEQ_DADOS_CADASTRAIS.NEXTVAL,
         --SYSDATE,
         PAN.ATSF_NOME,
         GE.ATSF_NOME AS GESTOR,
         PAN.PKSF_CHAPA,
         PAN.FKSF_CCUSTO,
         QUA.ATSF_FUN_PORT_EXT AS CARGO,
         COMP.ATSF_CO_PORT_EXT AS UO,
         AREA.ATSF_AREA_PORT_ABR,

         'P',
         '1'
     FROM 
         PANA101V_EMPREGADO PAN 
         LEFT JOIN TAKB100T_EMPREGADO  EMP  ON PAN.PKSF_CHAPA = EMP.PKND_NUMERO_PESSOAL
         LEFT JOIN PANA004T_COMPONENT COMP ON COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = PAN.FKND_COMP_ORGAN
         LEFT JOIN  PANA001T_QUALIFICA QUA ON QUA.PKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL = PAN.FKSF_FUNCAO
         LEFT JOIN PANA011T_AREA AREA ON AREA.PKSF_AREA = COMP.FKSF_AREA

         LEFT JOIN(SELECT
         S.CODFUNC,
         S.CODSUP,
         P.ATSF_NOME
         FROM TAKB437T_HIER_SAP S INNER JOIN PANA101V_EMPREGADO P ON S.CODFUNC = P.PKSF_CHAPA
         WHERE CODFUNC IN( SELECT PKND_NUMERO_PESSOAL FROM TAKB100T_EMPREGADO))GE ON PAN.PKSF_CHAPA = GE.CODSUP

         WHERE PKSF_CHAPA = 1705873
```

A tabela GE está errada, pois não está me trazendo os dados corretos. Precisa ser ajustada, eu sei, mas não sei fazer.
O que eu preciso fazer para resolver essa pendência? A tabela que possui o funcionário e gestor é essa: **PANA101V_EMPREGADO**.
As outras são para trazer outras informações.
Essa query vai popular um **INSERT** em uma outra tabela recem criada.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi corretamente basta apenas a tabela EMPREGADOS participar com dois papéis: EMPREGADOS e GESTOR:

```
SELECT
         --SEQ_DADOS_CADASTRAIS.NEXTVAL,
         --SYSDATE,
         PAN.ATSF_NOME,
         GESTOR.ATSF_NOME AS GESTOR,
         PAN.PKSF_CHAPA,
         PAN.FKSF_CCUSTO,
         QUA.ATSF_FUN_PORT_EXT AS CARGO,
         COMP.ATSF_CO_PORT_EXT AS UO,
         AREA.ATSF_AREA_PORT_ABR,
         'P',
         '1'
     FROM 
         PANA101V_EMPREGADO PAN 
         LEFT JOIN TAKB100T_EMPREGADO  EMP  ON PAN.PKSF_CHAPA = EMP.PKND_NUMERO_PESSOAL
         LEFT JOIN PANA004T_COMPONENT COMP ON COMP.PKSF_COMP_ORGAN = PAN.FKND_COMP_ORGAN
         LEFT JOIN PANA001T_QUALIFICA QUA ON QUA.PKSF_FUNCAO_NIVEL = PAN.FKSF_FUNCAO
         LEFT JOIN PANA011T_AREA AREA ON AREA.PKSF_AREA = COMP.FKSF_AREA
            LEFT JOIN TAKB437T_HIER_SAP S ON S.CODFUNC = PAN.CODFUNC
            LEFT JOIN PANA101V_EMPREGADO GESTOR ON GESTOR.CODSUP = PAN.CODSUP;
         WHERE PKSF_CHAPA = 1705873
```

Comment: Anonimo, não funcionou, pois não existe o PAN.CODSUP. Tentei altarar para PKSF_CHAPA, campo na tabela empregados, mas aí o Gestor e o Funcionário passam a ser a mesma pessoa.

Comment: Na realidade foi um erro de digitação.  Como disse é a mesma tabela EMPREGADOS mas no papel de gestor, portanto: `ON  S.CODSUP = GESTOR.CODFUNC`.

Comment: Não funcionou. Os joins não batem, fiz algumas alterações para funcionar, mas o Gestor é o mesmo Funcionário.